# Две карты Google Maps на одной странице

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как инициализировать две карты на одной странице?

Comment: Это русский SO, тут можно по-русски вопросы задавать. Ваш я перевел, не благодарите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет о `Google Map API V3`, то вот как-то так:

```js
     var map,map2;
    
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, -1),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
 
      var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53, -2),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      }
    
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                    myOptions);
     
      map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"),
                                    myOptions2);
```

```css
.karta {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas" class="karta"></div>
<div id="map_canvas2" class="karta"></div>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```